# Format phone number in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I have a 10 digit number , which needs to be displayed as formatted phone number.

```
Eg: 1234567890 needs to be formatted in (123) 456-7890
```

I have tried formatting it using built-ins for numbers in freemarker, but somehow still not able to get it in expected format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible with Java `SimpleNumberFormat` patterns, which is what FreeMarker uses when you write things like `'0.##'`. But there are no limitations with custom number formats (see http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_config_custom_formats.html), like, you could have something like `${n?string.@phone}` that can do all kind of Java logic.

However, I would like to note that perhaps there's a problem there in the data model itself. In reality, phone numbers are not numbers, but stings (or even structures). They can have significant characters in them like `+` (or even `#`). Not to mention `/`, in case you have to dial extensions.